# Print score in SDL with opengl using ostream?

Tags: c++, sdl

I am using the following code  to print in SDL screen:

```
SDL_GL_RenderText(  timer, font, color, &position);
sprintf(timer," Time : %d",time);
```

As I am doing project on C++, and  as `sprintf` is C style function, so I am not supposed to use sprintf, I am trying to use `ostringstream`, but I am not sure how  to  use it.

Somebody post the equivalent c++ style (using ostringstream or equivalent).

Comment: Did you try searching for `ostringstream` example codes, references, tutorials or anything on google?

Comment: And [this page from the first results of google search for ostringstream](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1992/OStringStream-or-how-to-stop-worrying-and-never-us) was not helpful enough?

Comment: I just saw your edit on the comment. Try posting the code you tried and tell us what you mean by "it didn't work". Also, from your example code, you may want to do `SDL_GL_RenderText(ostr.str(), ...)` rather than `cout`.

Comment: yea , even i tried

` ostringstream ostr;
 SDL_GL_RenderText( highs , font, color, &position);
 ostr<<highs<<"HighScore :"<<highscore;
 cout<<ostr.str(); `

but it is not working , i am not sure it is correct or not

Comment: This is my code
          ostringstream ostr;
           SDL_GL_RenderText( highs , font, color, &position);
           ostr<<highs<<"HighScore :"<<highscore;
           ostr.str();
           it doesn't print Highscore in output but it's sprintf                equivalent does..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of code you may find in any documentation or example..

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream str;
str << "Time: " << time;

// get the std::string
str.str();
// get the C char*
str.str().c_str();

// reset the string stream
str.str("Initial value");
```

So if you want to use the C char array

```
const char* text = str.str().c_str();
SDL_GL_RenderText(text, font, color, &position);
```

Another way to achieve this would be to wrap the calls to SDL_GL_RenderText with a custom `std::strbuf` and `std::ostream`, which will permit to do something like:

```
gl_out << font << color << position << "Timer :" << time << std::flush;
```

According the font, color and position have a real type and not something like void* or simply int. If this is the case you can wrap them with a custom type.

This method is a bit more complicated and requires a good understanding of the stream management in the standard C++ library, but it is IMO far more elegant. Though I never tried this with OpenGL, it worked with syslog (with log level specification) and other text output media.

Comment: i used 
'code'  sprintf(timer," Time : %d",time);//it works
but here in your code where is the character variable timer??

Comment: You can't access it directly, you have to format your string using ostringstream, then get the char array to do whatever you want with it. For example the second code snippet from my post